# Requesting an API which uses CORS on IE7

Tags: asp.net-web-api, internet-explorer-7, cors

I have created an ASP.NET Web API which uses [CORS](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api).

As [IE7 doesn't support CORS](http://caniuse.com/cors), what would be the result if I made a request from another origin to this API, using IE7?

Am I right in saying that as IE7 is pre-CORS, this would allow the API to be requested, and by-pass the cross-origin checks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same origin policy predates IE7.  Any browser that does not support CORS will simply not allow you to make cross-domain ajax requests.  The same origin policy is enforced in IE7.  Perhaps JSONP is an option for you.  Hard to say without more knowledge of your situation.  If JSONP is not an option for you, the request must be proxied from a server on the same origin when using IE7.